# AngularJS : directive inside ng-repeat not respecting new order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

First, [here's the issue reproduced in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WBM6dXpLvMovq4zTowWp).

Basically I have a directive that will insert some element based on some info inside an `ng-repeat`. For my application, I'm using a pretty similar approach where it inserts an `<img>`, `<video>`, or `<audio>` element based on a mime type.

You'll see that when items are reordered in the array the `ng-repeat` is using, the item passed to the `pageStyle` directive isn't up to date with the new order anymore. It seems to retain whatever was in its spot before.

```
app.directive('pageStyle', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      pageStyle: '='
    },
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var ele;
      switch (scope.pageStyle) {
        case 'bold':
          ele = angular.element('<b>bold</b>');
          break;
        case 'italics':
          ele = angular.element('<i>italics</i>');
          break;
        case 'strike':
          ele = angular.element('<strike>strikethrough</strike>');
          break;
      }
      element.append(ele);
    }
  };
});
```

So I suppose my main question is how I get the directive to reevaluate when the order within an `ng-repeat` is changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the use of 'track by'. 'track-by' causes not to re-build the dom elements completely, hence improves performance for ng-repeat rendering. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm

Your problem requires re-rendering. So, remove 'track by'.
You can check the issue by adding watch on pageStyle scope variable. That will give you clear insight of the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I was mistaken in how `track by` worked. I thought it was only necessary when I wanted to use `$index` within the markup, but it turns out it is injected anyway!